# Angular 4 animation don't resumed the initial CSS value

Tags: angular

I was in Angular 2 and I change for Angular 4.0.0 rc-2 and the animations behavior is not the same. In Angular 2 I was able to resumed the initial CSS value when it returned to the state "True" but this is no longer the case with Angular 4. Somebody can help me?

State on TRUE => I want to resumed the initial CSS value

State on False => Set width to 100%

I have this animation:

```
trigger('flyInOutX', [
    state('true', style({transform: 'translateX(0%)'})),
    state('false', style({width: '100%', transform:'translateX(-245px)'})),
    transition('* => *', animate('300ms')),
]),
```

Comment: Did you try to set `width: '*'` on state "true"? You should know that the angular team moved the animation features from `@angular/core` to `@angular/animations` and that there a quite a few existing issues regarding animations since `4.0.0-rc.1`

Comment: I try, but that doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation state needs to be a string value, so using a boolean won't work.

If you were doing `[@flyInOutX]="foo"` in your template, try doing `[@flyInOutX]="foo ? 'true' : 'false'"` instead.

Comment: Better late than never! You have right, for the string value